# How to make a loop break when using Lwt in OCaml

Tags: concurrency, ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I'm writing code to monitor the content of a file.  When the program reaches the end of the the file I want it to terminate cleanly.

```
let log () : input_channel Lwt.t = 
  openfile "log" [O_RDONLY] 0 >>= fun fd -> 
  Lwt.return (of_fd input fd);;

let rec loop (ic: input_channel) = Lwt_io.read_line ic >>= fun text -> 
    Lwt_io.printl text >>= fun _ -> loop ic;;

let monitor () : unit Lwt.t = log () >>= loop;;

let handler : exn -> unit Lwt.t = fun e -> match e with
    | End_of_file -> let (p: unit Lwt.t), r = Lwt.wait() in p
    | x -> Lwt.fail x;;

let main () : unit Lwt.t = Lwt.catch monitor handler;;

let _ = Lwt_main.run (main ());;
```

However, when reading a file and reaching the end, the program does not terminate, it just hangs and I have to escape with Ctrl+c.  I am not sure what is going on under the hood with bind but I figured whatever it's doing, eventually `Lwt_io.readline ic` should eventually hit the end of the file and return an `End_of_file` exception, which presumably would get passed over to the handler, etc.

If I had to guess at a resolution, I would think maybe in the last bind of the definition of `>>=` I would include some `if` check.  But I'd be checking, I think, whether `Lwt_io.read_line` returned `End_of_file`, which I though should be handled by the `handler`.

Comment: I don't really know much about Lwt, but from a naive reading of the code I'm not surprised it hangs since on `End_of_file` you call `wait` and then throw away the resolver. So of course it waits.... Any reason why you're not using `return ()` instead here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Lwt.wait` function creates a promise which could only be resolved using the second element of the returned pair, basically, this function will never terminate:

```
let never_ready () = 
  let (p,_) = Lwt.wait in
  p
```

and this is exactly what you've written.

Concerning a graceful termination, ideally, you should do this in the `loop` function so that you can close the channel and prevent leaking of the valuable resources, e.g.,

```
let rec loop (ic: input_channel) = 
  Lwt_io.read_line ic >>= function
  | exception End_of_file -> 
    Lwt.close ic
  | text->
    Lwt_io.printl text >>= fun () -> 
    loop ic
```

The minimum change to your code would be, however, to use `Lwt.return ()` instead of `Lwt.wait` in the body of your `handler`.